# creating tables in visual studio sql

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2017, foreign-keys

i get this error when i execute 
SQL71516 :: The referenced table '[dbo].[Stock]' contains no primary or candidate keys that match the referencing column list in the foreign key. If the referenced column is a computed column, it should be persisted.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Customer]
(
[Id] INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY, 
[FirstName] NCHAR(10) NOT NULL, 
[LastName] NCHAR(10) NOT NULL, 
[Email] NCHAR(10) NOT NULL UNIQUE, 
[Mobile] NCHAR(10) NOT NULL

)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Stock]
(
[Id] INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY, 
[name] NCHAR(10) NOT NULL, 
[price] INT NOT NULL,
CustomersID int NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY (CustomersID) REFERENCES Customer(Id)
ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Order]
(
[Id] INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY, 
[Date] DATE NOT NULL, 
[Quantity] INT NOT NULL,  
Stock_price int NOT NULL,
[Total Value] AS (Quantity)*(Stock_price) PERSISTED, 
CONSTRAINT [FK_Stock_price1] FOREIGN KEY ([Stock_price])
REFERENCES [Stock](price) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only use columns that are uniquely indexed. The `price` column is not. However, I suspect that the foreign key that's giving you a hard time is actually wrong anyway. I also don't think you should have a `CustomerId` reference in your `Stock` table.

in fact, the basic standard database structure for a store is this:

```
Customer table
    id, name [, other details]

Stock table
    id, name, price [, other details]

Order table
    id, customer id, order date [, other details]

Order details table
    id, order id, item id, quantity, price [, other details]
```

This way, an order is related to a single customer, an can contain multiple items.
The price column in the order details table represents the item price at the date of the order - while the price column in the stock table represents the item's current price.

Comment: i want the Customer to buy one or more stock and  Each order has only one stock. So if customer want to buy from to stock so he enters to orders in the database.

Answer (score 0):

`[Stock].[price]` is not a key, that's why you can't define a foreign key on that column.

If 2 products (A and B) in table `Stock` have the same `price`, what would be the reference?

You can either set a key on this column, such as `UNIQUE` but this will prevent you to have differents prices in your table `Stock`.

I suggest you to use the `[Stock].[Id]` key as reference for your foreign key, such as :

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Order]
(
    [Id] INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY, 
    [Date] DATE NOT NULL, 
    [Quantity] INT NOT NULL,  
    Stock_id int NOT NULL, -- <--- changed column name
    [Total Value] AS (Quantity)*(Stock_price) PERSISTED, 
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Stock_id1] FOREIGN KEY ([Stock_id]) -- <-- changed column name
    REFERENCES [Stock](Id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
    --                ^--^------------------------------------- Notice this
);
```